# Add Hyperlink below the Card or table visual Conditionally in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a  Power-Bi Report where I need to show the hyperlink in the card or table conditionally. the report is having Account_id as slicer value.

If an account_id results more than 4 records in the visual, I need to add a extra row with text `"More.."` in it. Reference image is below.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If more than 4... then what?

Comment: sorry edited the question

Comment: Where does the "More.." text link to?

Comment: it will point to actual report when click on it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't if it's possible to get exactly what you want, but here's my attempt. Power BI still isn't great if you need a lot of control over formatting.

---

First, create a ranking column:

```
Rank = RANKX(
           FILTER(ALL(Table1),
               Table1[account_id] = EARLIER(Table1[account_id])),
           Table1[Partners], , ASC)
```

Next, a column that displays the top ones and "More..." for any possible 5th items.

```
Display = IF(Table1[Rank] > 5,
             BLANK(),
             IF(Table1[Rank] < 5,
                 Table1[Partners],
                 "More..."))
```

Finally, a column that contains the desired URL for the "More..." rows:

```
Link = IF(Table1[Display] = "More...", "http://www.URL.com", BLANK())
```

Here's what my sample data table looks like:

[image: Sample Data]

Then you can set up a table with the `Display` and `Link` column. Make sure to choose "Don't summarize" for the field and choose [URL icon on under values formatting options](http://analyticsavenue.com/power-bi-shorten-hyperlink-url/) to get the link icon instead of a URL. You'll probably also want to filter out blanks in your visual fitter settings.

[image: Example]

For the right-hand table above I changed the column header texts to "Partners" and " " in the table Values box.

Comment: could you tell what table style you have used?

Comment: It's a basic table with Table style to None and just some text sizes, fonts, and background/border set. The URL icon requires you to have at least the April update version of Power BI and is explained more fully in the link I included.